# How can I create a raw-vegan puddings?

Tags: vegan, pudding

I want to make a raw-vegan *firm white pudding* based on water and/or some vegan milk.

How an I achieve a firm texture?

- Bananas can have strong banana flavor which may take over other tastes
- Chia seeds and/or basil seeds might help but the firmness might be "very soft firmness" and tiny black seeds might bias a customer to think that the course is not really a traditional pudding alternative

To be honest, a [silken tofu (soft tofu) block](https://www.google.com/search?q=silken%20tofu&rlz=1C1CHBD_enTH852TH852&sxsrf=AOaemvKG1d9THhSpNaKdHRe-jHgMLp2w1Q:1642949181492&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-r-LSjsj1AhWehP0HHVjiAYAQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw#imgrc=RyT05runHA4VaM) looks just like what I expect as a white pudding but it often has significant soy flavor, which often isn't suitable for desserts.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use cornflour? (corn starch)

Comment: Tofu pudding is a perfectly legitimate thing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douhua), it can be as simple as cold tofu with syrup.

Answer (score 2):

Tofu is not raw.

Xanthan and guar thicken without heating.
Nutbutter will thicken well also adding richness.
Coconut cream will add thickening to chilled pudding and definitely gives you 'white'.

A slightly underripe banana won't add a strong flavor and does thicken up in fridge. May need some acid or pudding will darken.

Depending how firm you need, a combination of above should do it.

Comment: Is coconut cream raw?

Comment: When I buy in the market, yes. Canned, I imagine, has been pastuerized.

Comment: Most definitions I found said boiling was part of the process.